# Existence of $\lim_{k\to +\infty}\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin^2x}{\sqrt{1-\frac{k^2}{k^2+1} \,\sin^2x} + \sqrt{1-\sin^2x}}\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, analysis

> Prove that existence of limit $$\lim_{k\to +\infty}\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin^2x}{\sqrt{1-\frac{k^2}{k^2+1} \,\sin^2x} + \sqrt{1-\sin^2x}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

*Attempt*.

Let $A_k$ be the $k$-th term of the sequence. Then $(A_k)$ is increasing. If we proved that it is upper bounded, then we would have convergence. But the estimation:
$$\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin^2x}{\sqrt{1-\frac{k^2}{k^2+1} \,\sin^2x} + \sqrt{1-\sin^2x}}\,\mathrm{d}x\leqslant \frac12\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin^2x}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}}\,\mathrm{d}x=+\infty,$$
although corrent, seems to overestimate the integral.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think you're right It does not converges. To show this provably you need a lower bound for the integrand.

Comment: Form the integral we get $$\left(k^2+1\right)
   \left(E\left(\frac{k^2}{k^2+1}\right)-1\right)$$

Comment: ... and the limit of @Dr.SonnhardGraubner's result is $\infty$.

Comment: @GEdgar Is it? It is of the form $\infty*0$. It seems that it could actually exist.

Comment: @pisoir ... I used Maple, which knows asymptotics for the elliptic integral $E$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

For fixed $x \in (0,\pi/2)$, the integrand
$$
\frac{\sin^2x}{\sqrt{1-\frac{k^2}{k^2+1} \,\sin^2x} + \sqrt{1-\sin^2x}}
$$
increases as $k$ increases. The integrand is nonnegative.  So by the monotone convergence theorem,
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin^2x}{\sqrt{1-\frac{k^2}{k^2+1} \,\sin^2x} + \sqrt{1-\sin^2x}}\;dx \\=
\int_0^{\pi/2}\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{\sin^2x}{\sqrt{1-\frac{k^2}{k^2+1} \,\sin^2x} + \sqrt{1-\sin^2x}}\;dx \\=
\int_0^{\pi/2}\;\frac{\sin^2x}{2\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}}\;dx = +\infty
$$

Comment: Of course! Thank you. By the way, can we determine the behaviour of $\frac{A_k}{k^2+1}$ (indefinite form: $0\cdot \infty$)?