# Prove or disprove: $\lim_{a\to 1^-}E(a)=1$ for $E(a)$ elliptic integral of second kind

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits, riemann-integration

> Let $E(a)=\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{1-a^2\sin^2t}\,\mathrm{d}t,~~0<a<1$ be the elliptic integral of second kind. Prove or disprove: $$\displaystyle \lim_{a\to 1^-}E(a)=\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{1-\sin^2t}\,\mathrm{d}t=1.$$

*Attempt.*
$$0<E(a)-\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
$$=\left(1-a^2\right) \int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin^2x}{\sqrt{1-a^2 \,\sin^2x} + \sqrt{1-\sin^2x}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
so we need to evaluate the limit of the last expression (in my post 
[Existence of $\lim_{k\to +\infty}\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin^2x}{\sqrt{1-\frac{k^2}{k^2+1} \,\sin^2x} + \sqrt{1-\sin^2x}}\,\mathrm{d}x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3477103/existence-of-lim-k-to-infty-int-limits-0-frac-pi2-frac-sin2x?noredirect=1#comment7148948_3477103)
 the answer was that the sequence tends to $+\infty$, so in our case we get indefinite form $0\cdot\infty$).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This seems like a lot of extra work. Why not compute the integral $E(1)$ directly?

Comment: I am interested in the (general) behaviour of $E(a)$ as a tends to $1$, not just the value $E(1)=1$.

Comment: Lebesgue dominated convergence?

Comment: May we use tools only from Riemann integration theory (if possible)?

Comment: Just use uniform convergence theorem

Comment: You mean: for continuous $f_n's$ that converge uniformly to $f$ on $[a,b]$, the integrals of $f_n's$ also converge to the integral of $f$?

Comment: @NikolaosSkout It's easier to use the bounded convergence theorem, with $f_n(t)=\sqrt{1-(1-1/n)^2\sin ^2 t}$.

Comment: There is no elementary proof that uses for example basic inequalities and squeeze techniques?

Comment: @NikolaosSkout You can do an $\epsilon - \delta$ proof but I don't think it's easier.

Comment: @NikolaosSkout You would need to show that $\int_0^{\pi/2}(\sqrt{1-a^2\sin ^2 t }- 2/\pi ) dt <  \epsilon $ whenever $|a-1| < \delta$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integrand $f(t, a) $ is continuous on $[0,\pi/2]\times[0,1]$ and hence the integral $E(a) $ is continuous on $[0,1]$. It follows trivially that $$\lim_{a\to 1^{-}}E(a)=E(1)=1$$

Answer (score 1):

Using Mathematica notations,
$$\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{1-a^2\sin^2t}\,dt=E\left(a^2\right)$$ and its expansion around $a=1$ is given by
$$E\left(a^2\right)\sim 1-\frac{1}{2} (1-a) \left(\log \left(\frac{1-a}{8}\right)+1\right)+\cdots$$

Let $a=1-10^{-k}$ and compare the numerical values
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 1 & 1.16910133173369 & 1.17169705278161 \\
 2 & 1.02842305863834 & 1.02847580902880 \\
 3 & 1.00399359841033 & 1.00399440996551 \\
 4 & 1.00051448909568 & 1.00051450008378 \\
 5 & 1.00006296183503 & 1.00006296197369 \\
 6 & 1.00000744747605 & 1.00000744747772
\end{array}
\right)$$